How to prevent image to get black background when converting from PDF using ImageMagick or Mogrify?
I'm trying to use an ImageMagick CLI command to convert multiple files from PDF to JPG format, but some images get a black background when the original file has a transparent background.
I'm using the following command:
mogrify -colorspace sRGB -density 600 -resize 1080 -background white -format jpg *.pdf


Finally I solved that problem adding the -flatten parameter:
mogrify -colorspace sRGB -density 600 -resize 1080 -background white -flatten -format jpg *.pdf

